# R plot too zoomed in

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot my data as a scatterplot seems like there is something wrong with my preferences so that I cannot see the entire graph

I tried the following example from [QuickR](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html)

```
# Simple Scatterplot
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg, main="Scatterplot Example", 
    xlab="Car Weight ", ylab="Miles Per Gallon ", pch=19)
```

Instead of the result, I can only see the dots but only a fraction of the title and no axes because the plot seems to be too "zoomed-in". How can I solve this issue?

Best

Comment: The plot is fine on my machine. Does the problem persist in a newly opened R session?

Comment: Is there a similar plot that works fine, or is this an issue with all your plots? Also, are you using the R GUI or RStudio (or something else)?

Comment: The problem persists if I restart R. I am using RStudio